# Редактирование захэшированных паролей

Tags: php

Для редактирования пароля нужно вписать старый и новый. Как проверить старый пароль на схожесть? Пароли в бд хранятся в ХЭШ sha1

Comment: что значит проверить на схожесть? на схожесть с чем?

Answer (score 3):

Введенный старый пароль обработайте функцией [sha1()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sha1.php) и полученный результат сравните со значением хранящимся в базе.